# Mapping RawSql Result to Object in Java Ebean

Tags: java, orm, ebean

Let's say I have a class `Article` which is automatically mapped by Java Ebean as a database table.

For this table I wanted to retrieve entries via a `RawSql` query, because I find SQL more simple when it gets to complex queries with many joins and such. By far I have managed to give my SQL statement to the Parser. The query is correct, I already checked that.

The only problem is, that I don't know, how to map the database results to my `Article` class. I know, that there is a `columnMapping(...)` method but honestly, I am to lazy to map every single column manually...

Isn't there another way to just like `myResults.mapToClass(Article.class)` to retrieve something like a `List<Article>`?

This is the code I already have:

```
Finder<String, Article> find = new Finder<String, Article>(
        String.class, Article.class);
String sql = "SELECT * FROM article [...]";
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create();
List<Article> returnList = find.setRawSql(rawSql).findList();
```

Alternatively:

```
Finder<String, Article> find = new Finder<String, Article>(
                String.class, Article.class);
String sql = "SELECT id, title, sub_title FROM article [...]";
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql)
            .columnMapping("id", "id")
            .columnMapping("title", "title")
            .columnMapping("sub_title", "subTitle")
            .create();
List<Article> resultList = find.setRawSql(rawSql).findList();
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Anybody found a solution for this?

Comment: pinging this issue. I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of happened in Ebean since the question was asked, but I think the problem is still valid. the new RawSqlBuilder.tableMapping() makes things easier as can be seen in the code below, but afaik it still needs manual mapping of all attributes (no `SELECT table.* FROM table`)

I have this exact problem, and worked around this by creating a helper object (@Entity/@Sql) that I map to. E.g. [CustomerWithPurchaseStats](https://github.com/tobias-/ebean-problems/blob/ebean_rawsql_test/src/main/java/com/foo/myapp/domain/CustomerWithPurchaseStats.java).

Extract:

```
@Entity
@Sql
public class CustomerWithPurchaseStats {

    @OneToOne
    private Customer customer;
...
```

And in the [DAO](https://github.com/tobias-/ebean-problems/blob/ebean_rawsql_test/src/main/java/com/foo/myapp/domain/CustomerDAO.java):

```
public List<CustomerWithPurchaseStats> getAllCustomersWithPurchaseStats() {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT cu.id, <manually add all fields you need mapped ").append(" FROM customer cu ");
    RawSqlBuilder rawSqlBuilder = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql.toString());
    rawSqlBuilder.tableAliasMapping("cu", "customer").create();
    return Ebean.find(CustomerWithPurchaseStats.class)
                .setRawSql(rawSqlBuilder.create())
                .findList();
}
```